# Is it possible to use Spring Integration for batch processes with ExecutorChannel or Pollers with Task Executors

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am trying to use Spring Integration for a batch process. There are certain steps that are time consuming and hence would benefit with a QueueChannel with multiple consumers each running on a separate thread.

The problem with this approach is that there is no clean way to shut-down the application after all the messages have been consumed. I have tried using a control bus and shutting down the task executor but that only works if you can guess by what time all messages would have been consumed and none are in flight which is impossible.

Is there a clean way to do this for a batch process or is this just a wrong use case to use Spring Integration in ?

EDIT:

Essentially it would be nice if there was a way for me to send a special message which signifies one of the lifecycle events like start or stop which is automatically carried through all the spring integration components. This way the stop message is guaranteed to reach last and if there is a way to trigger shutdown() on the *lifecycle* aware beans when stop message reaches them.

Answer (score 0):

> shut-down the application after all the messages have been consumed

If you know the number of messages in the beginning, you can have an `AtomicInteger` bean and increment it every time a message is processed. Separately you have an inbound channel adapter to poll the current state of that `AtomicInteger` and make a decision to shutdown your app.

Alternatively you can use an aggregator to gather results for all the messages and shutdown the app in the downstream flow after that aggregator.

Comment: If its not possible to predict how many messages can arrive and there is a huge variation in number of messages being processed then is it possible ?
I wouldn't want to guess how many messages there can be.

Essentially it would be nice if there was a way for me to send a special message which signifies one of the lifecycle events like start or stop which is automatically carried through all the spring integration components. This way the stop message is guaranteed to reach last and if there is a way to trigger shutdown() on the lifecycleaware beans when stop message reaches them.

Comment: What is the source of messages? Can't it be so infinite that you just don't have a reason to stop your application at all? Can't that source send a "stop" message for you otherwise? It is possible to stop application by itself if there are no activity for a while. See `SimpleActiveIdleMessageSourceAdvice` for example.